# Select Grouping query

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns two items for each 'SENDER_REFERENCE_NB', one where the MESSAGE_STATUS is '(Receive)', and the other where the MESSAGE_STATUS is 'Matched'. Both contain a CREATE_TM

```
select MESSAGE_ID, CREATE_TM, MESSAGE_STATUS
from TMS_MESSAGE_AUDIT_LOG
where message_id in (select message_id from tms_message
                     WHERE SENDER_REFERENCE_NB like '150703%')
  and MESSAGE_STATUS in ('(Receive)', 'Matched');
```

What I would like to achieve, is for each SENDER_REFERENCE_NB, I see the  ('Receive') status & CREATE_TM associated to this entry and the 'Matched' status and CREATE_TM associated, all on the one row.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to get a definitive answer with your question as it currently stands.  Can you add your schema and also make the question more clear?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I think you will have to JOIN the tables (instead of the sub-select) and possibly use PIVOT to get what you want.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions, here is my answer:

```
Select L1.MESSAGE_ID, L1.CREATE_TM, L1.MESSAGE_STATUS, 
       L2.MESSAGE_ID, L2.CREATE_TM, L2.MESSAGE_STATUS
from TMS_MESSAGE_AUDIT_LOG AS L1
INNER JOIN TMS_MESSAGE_AUDIT_LOG AS L2
ON L1.MESSAGE_STATUS = '(Receive)'
AND L1.SENDER_REFERENCE_NB like '150703%'
AND L2.SENDER_REFERENCE_NB like '150703%'
AND L2.MESSAGE_STATUS = 'Matched'
```

You can see it in operation [in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/863314/3).